# pandas groupby select cells on condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to group my Dataframe, and then count the mean of the dummy occurance per group.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Number':['001','001','001','002','002','002','002'],
                   'name':['peter','chris','meg','albert','cathrine','leo','leo'],
                   'dummy':[0,1,1,0,0,1,1]})
```

i could calculate the mean number of unique occurances (based on names) per group using this code:

```
test=df3.groupby('Number')
test_1 = []
for name, group in test:
    x= len(group.name.unique())
    test_1.append(x)
pd.Series(test_1).mean()
```

now i want to calculate how often the dummy equals to 1 on average in a group given that the name is unique

> so for this example the calculation would be (2+1)/2 =1.5.
>   where ( unique dummy counts from group 1 (2) +  unique dummy count from group 2 (1))/divided by number of groups (2) =1.5 unique dummy counts on average per group

note that if there is no dummy in the group, the number of groups in the denominator should still increase by 1

Please comment if i didnt express the task clearly!

Comment: The group is the `'Number'` column?

Comment: yes just recognized that i forgot it in the initial version of the question ;)

Comment: But here the second group has two `'dummy'`s set to `1` as well?

Comment: exactly... this is why i am using the `name.unique()`

Comment: What is the expected output given the input above?

Comment: What if there is a group with no `dummy`s? Do you take this into account or not?

Comment: yes even if there is no dummy in the group, this should still increase the number of groups

Answer (score 0):

```
s = df3.groupby('Number').agg({"name":["nunique"], "dummy": ["sum"]})
sum(s["name"]["nunique"]/s["dummy"]["sum"])
```

If I understand correctly what you meant

And in a more elegant implementation -

```
def my_func(x):
     n = x['name'].nunique()
     s = x['dummy'].sum()
     return n/s

df3.groupby('Number').apply(my_func).mean()
```

**Edit**

I finally think that I understood after see the suggested solution by the question asker -

```
df4 = df3[df3.dummy == 1]

df4.groupby('Number').apply(lambda x: x["name"].nunique()).sum()/df4.Number.nunique()
```

Comment: the output of your function is 3 but 1.5 is expected. Also if you vary a 1 to a 0 in group one so that the calculation would be (1+1)/2 =1 your function gives 4.5 as output

Comment: I fixed something in my solution and read your question again, I think it is not clear and you should explain it in more details

Comment: your function gives still the same output as i mentioned in my earlier comment

Comment: unfortunately the function still doesnt work properly: you can see for yourself if you change the dummies to `[0,1,0,0,0,1,1]` your function returns 2, while mine would return 1

Answer (score 0):

Ok i just found an answer to my question, even though it is a little workaround:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Number':['001','001','001','002','002','002','002'],
                   'name':['peter','chris','meg','albert','cathrine','leo','leo'],
                   'dummy':[0,1,0,0,0,1,1]})

df4=df3.loc[df3.dummy.isin(['1'])] #creating new dataframe with only the rows where dummy = 1

test=df4.groupby('Number') # group it by the number column

test_1 = []
for name, group in test:
    x= len(group.name.unique()) #take  only the unique names in each group
    test_1.append(x)
pd.Series(test_1).sum()/len(test) # divide value count by number of groups
```